# ML code - NameError: name 'prepare_country_stats' is not defined

Tags: machine-learning, nameerror

This is the ML code. I am getting the `NameError: name 'prepare_country_stats' is not defined`. Can someone please point out the mistake that I am missing out. I shall be very grateful.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn

oecd_bli = pd.read_csv("oecd_bli_2015.csv", thousands = ',')
gdp_per_capita = pd.read_csv("GDP.csv", thousands=',',delimiter='\t', encoding='latin1', na_values="n/a")

country_stats = prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli_2015, GDP)
X = np.c_[country_stats["GDP per capita"]]
y = np.c_[country_stats["Life Satisfaction"]]

country_stats.plot(kind='scatter', x="GDP per capita", y='Life satisfaction')
plt.show()

model=sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()

model.fit(X,y)

X_new=[[22587]]
print(model.predict(X_new))
```

Comment: what is the: prepare_country_stats ? a function ? where do you define the function ?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want.

```
def prepare_country_stats(oecd_bli, gdp_per_capita):
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli[oecd_bli["INEQUALITY"]=="TOT"]
    oecd_bli = oecd_bli.pivot(index="Country", columns="Indicator", values="Value")
    gdp_per_capita.rename(columns={"2015": "GDP per capita"}, inplace=True)
    gdp_per_capita.set_index("Country", inplace=True)
    full_country_stats = pd.merge(left=oecd_bli, right=gdp_per_capita,
                                  left_index=True, right_index=True)
    full_country_stats.sort_values(by="GDP per capita", inplace=True)
    remove_indices = [0, 1, 6, 8, 33, 34, 35]
    keep_indices = list(set(range(36)) - set(remove_indices))
    return full_country_stats[["GDP per capita", 'Life satisfaction']].iloc[keep_indices]
```

From here:

https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/01_the_machine_learning_landscape.ipynb

Answer (score 4):

This is example 1-1 from Géron's book: *Hands-On Machine Learning*.
In this case, if you just copy-paste the code it's not going to work. In fact, at the previous page, footnote 6 says:

> The code assumes that prepare_country_stats() is already defined: it merges the GDP and life satisfaction data into a single Pandas dataframe.

So they assume you've already wrote that function by yourself.
Hope this helps!

---

EDIT

This worked for the first edition of Géron's book. Now the second is out, and the book changed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `prepare_country_stats` is a function, where you have passed `oecd_bli_2015` and `GDP`. You need to have this function defined somewhere in your script. (Likewise, it appears that `GDP` is not defined).

Answer (score 0):

look to the prepare_country_state method you pass the wrong argument
you directly pass the data into it.